# Add REST controller/route to SpringBoot test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

Is it possible to add a route/endpoint (which I don't want to include in the sources, but rather leave it in the tests) to a SpringBoot test?

```
@RestController
class HelloAPI {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String ok() {
        return "world";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
As it turned out no extra configuration is needed - `HelloAPI` class should be moved from `src/main` to `src/test`. That's it. However, it will be "visible" to all @SpringBoot tests.

So the question is: how can I restrict the creation (registration in the ApplicationContext) of this bean (HelloAPI) to a particular test class?

[See link to an example project](https://github.com/maslick/rest-test/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/com/example/testrest/TestrestApplicationTests.kt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `@TestConfiguration` for this:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT)
class EmbeddedApiTest {

    @Test
    void testSomething() {
        ...
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestCfg {

        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/test")
        public class TestApi {

            @GetMapping("/hello")
            public String hello() {
                return "Hello World!";
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a static [inner](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) `@Configuration` class in which the bean is set up:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
... // Other test annotations
public class YourTestClass {

    @Configuration
    static class ContextConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public HelloAPI helloAPI() {
            return new HelloAPI();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void someTest_shouldXxx() { ... }
}
```

And be sure to add your `HelloAPI` class in `/src/test` instead of `/src/main/`.

Note however that `(test)ApplicationContext` will be destroyed after all the tests in the class have been performed, thereby destroying the `HelloAPI` bean as well.

If you are looking for way to offer test-endpoints to a `RestTemplate`, bind a `MockRestServiceServer` to your `RestTemplate` [instead](https://www.baeldung.com/restclienttest-in-spring-boot).

Comment: If I put HelloAPI class into ``/src/test`` it will be picked up by component scan ``automatically`` (due to the @RestController annotation), so neither static @Configuration, nor any @TestConfiguration is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have accepted Anatoliy's answer (who is using Java and JUnit5), I would like to share my Kotlin code (with the good old JUnit4):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
class TestWithInnerConfigTest {
    @LocalServerPort var port: Int? = null
    @Autowired private lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate

    @Test
    fun testingMainEndpoint() {
        val url = "http://localhost:$port/helloworld"
        val resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, GET, null, String::class.java)
        assertEquals(resp.statusCode, OK)
    }

    @Test
    fun testingTestEndpoint() {
        val url = "http://localhost:$port/test"
        val resp = restTemplate.exchange(url, GET, null, String::class.java)
        assertEquals(resp.statusCode, NOT_FOUND)
    }

    companion object {
        @TestConfiguration
        class TestCfg {
            @RestController
            class TestApi {
                @GetMapping("/test") fun hello() = "Helloworld!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The good thing about using a static inner `@TestConfiguration` class is that it is applied to only this file. Here is the [link to the complete example](https://github.com/maslick/rest-test/blob/master/src/test/kotlin/com/example/testrest/TestWithInnerConfigTest.kt).